# Wordpress, ghost, spurt commerce or any other cms?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, ghost-blog, spurt

I'm a web designer/developer. I'm too much confused whether to use cms or not and why? and which cms to use if i have to (like wordpress, ghost, spurt commerce).

Answer (score 2):

download spurtcommerce new version, and use it..
because it was developed with nodejs and angularjs.